# Difference between multinomial logit regression and multinomial logistic regression

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, logit, multinomial-logit

Is there a difference between the two models

1. Multinomial logit regression
2. Multinomial logistic regression?

Comment: Both are same [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)

Answer (score 3):

They are the same. Logit and logistic are inverse functions of each other (i.e: $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f(x)$). Therefore in statistical softwares and usage, the terms are actually referring to the same thing.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/120364/132847 for difference between logit and logistic.